# Video file is lagging out html page

Tags: amazon-s3, html5-video, video-processing, corruption, video-codecs

I uploaded a video file to s3 from my app today and the file is causing the page to lag out when I scroll up and down.

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hmd0j4aL/1/) that replicates the issue.

```
    <video style="width: 200px" id="video-player" class="w-full" playsinline="" controls="" src="https://bjj-mentor-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/feedback-requests/11c2190c-85cc-446c-895d-048c5adbad22/35f92e3f-4923-4c32-8085-0908cc2ce812.mov"></video>
```

Is there a codec issue?

Uploaded MOV file to s3. Expecting it to render easily.

I also converted it to mp4, webm, etc, and the issue remained, but I ran a "repair" from a paid service and the demo seemed to work better.